# Многопоточность в Ruby

Tags: многопоточность, ruby

Как в ruby изолировать две части программы, если одна из них должна каждые 5 минут получать данные с сайта post-запросом, а вторая обрабатывать их, при этом не работая по этому расписанию?

Comment: https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid но стоит ли таких сложностей?

Comment: Использовать сервер очередей, а вместе с ним воркеров и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Создай две программы

Первая - вызывается из `cron`.
Вторая вызывается из первой и обрабатывается данные.

или `bash` скрипт с `cron` запускает последовательно обе.